# jQueryUI remove event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events

I have created a [jQueryUI sortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) using the following code:

```
function markAsUpdated(){
      updated = true;
      alert('updated')
      jQuery( ".sortable" ).off('sortupdate', '**', markAsUpdated);
}


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery(".sortable").sortable({
             'cursor':'pointer',
              'items':'li',
              ....
             'update' : markAsUpdated
       }).disableSelection();
 }
```

What's meant to happen is the first time the update event is run in the sortable, the "markAsUpdated" function should run. However, I only want it to run the FIRST time it is updated.

The above code does not work, as the function continues to run even after the first time.

Answer (score 0):

**Add a counter**

```
var count = 0;

function markAsUpdated(){
      if (count == 0) {
        updated = true;
        alert('updated')
        jQuery( ".sortable" ).off('sortupdate', '**', markAsUpdated);
        count++;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thats not exactly what I wanted. I wanted to learn how to physically remove the event handler for 'sortupdate' so it is not run at all!